# res.send() does corrupt PDFs but not textfiles

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I am downloading files from sharepoint online. Frontend is running react and backend nodeJS with express.
On the frontend I have a working example to directly download files without backend.
Code:

```
const SPfetchFile = async (file) => {
    await axios.get(
        URL, 
        { headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + TOKEN },
        responseType: 'blob'
    }).then((response) => {
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', file.FileLeafRef);
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
    }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

Which results in a working file - [browser response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Sbq6.png)

However to increase security and not expose tokens to the browser I want to handle the download from backend and just pass the file to the frontend.

NodeJS backend:

```
exports.getSPFile = async(req, res) => {
  let config = {
      method: 'get',
      url: URL,
      responseType: 'blob',
      headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + token }
    };

    try{
      let res =  await axios(config)
      res.set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
      res.send(res.data)
    } catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Frontend:

```
const SPfetchFile = async (file) => {
    let response = await SharePointService.getSPFile(file) // executes "getSPFile" on backend
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response]));
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', file.name);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click(); 
    }
```

which does NOT result in a working file - [browser response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iUtE.png)

So basically I can fetch a working file with axios on frontend, but if I send the same axios response over res.send() it´s not working. Weird part: If I download only textfiles it´s working in both scenarios. But images and pdfs won´t work..

Comment: You have the same name `res` for the second argument of `getSPFile`  and for the variable in `let res =  await axios(config)`.